# Populating the view using data from db and has its values populate as radio buttons in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I have 2 models in codeigniter as follows, Question class can have 1 or many answers. I have come up with the following models.

```
class Answer{
    private $id ;
    private $question;
    private $answer;
}

class Question{
    private $id;
    private $answerList = array();

    public function setAnswerList($answer){
        $this->answerListList[] = $answer;
    }
    public function getAnswerList(){
        return $this->answerList;
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is first iterate the questions and pass them to the view. That I was able to do. And then I need to get the answers array to be displayed as radio buttons in each questions as in a MCQ format. How can I do so. Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With questions mode, fetch all questions. Next pass the question id and get the options which your have stored in your db.

```
fetch questions here
forreach(questions){
   pass question id and get its options.  
}
```

Your array should look like this,

```
$array[questions][question_id_from_db][question] = "question from db";
$array[questions][question_id_from_db][options] = "options from db";
```

In view

```
foreach($questions as $row){
    echo $row->question;
    foreach($row->options as $row1) {
         echo form_radio();// pass requiored parameters.
    }
}
```